# How can I keep detecting clouds(points) but making the image background to be black?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, directx

The class is a bit long and working.
The cone is rotating 360 degrees and any clouds inside the cone area are painting in yellow.

But what I want to do now is that the background image will be in black and only when the cone is rotating over a cloud/s then light them in yellow only when the cone is passing over them one he moved on close the detected clouds. I mean like display the detected clouds only when the cone is passing over them.

What I'm getting today is the original image and when the cone is moving over clouds it's making them yellow:

This screenshot showing what happen when the cone is over clouds.

[image: Screenshot]

And this screenshot showing when the cone is not over any clouds:

[image: Screenshot2]

Now what I want to do is instead displaying the original image in the class I called the variable: bmpWithClouds

I need the bmpWithClouds to scan the clouds but after it I want to use empty black image 512,512 resolution and to make that only when the cone is passing over a cloud/s then show them in yellow.

Then later I want to add my own points(pixels = clouds) make them move random in the black image and when the cone will pass over them to show them.

This is how I'm using the DopplerRadar class in form1 constructor:

```
DopplerRadar dr = new DopplerRadar();
dr.pb1 = pictureBox1;
dr.Init();
```

And this is the DopplerRadar class a bit long:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D;
using Microsoft.DirectX;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Diagnostics;


namespace mws
{
    class DopplerRadar
    {
        [DllImport("msvcrt.dll", EntryPoint = "memset", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, SetLastError = false)]
        public static extern IntPtr MemSet(IntPtr dest, int c, int count);

        private System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1;
        private Stream mymem;
        private Bitmap ConvertedBmp;
        private Device D3Ddev = null;
        private PresentParameters D3Dpp = null;
        private DisplayMode DispMode;
        private Sprite D3Dsprite = null;
        private Texture backTexture = null;
        private Texture scannedCloudsTexture = null;
        private byte[] argbValuesOfTransparentTexture;
        private float distanceFromCenterPixels;
        private float distanceFromCenterKm = 200F;
        private List<Point> detectedPoints;
        private float[] angleArray, distanceArray;
        private double angleCalculation, distance;
        private Bitmap bmpnew = new Bitmap(512, 512);
        private int bytes = 2048 * 512;
        public System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pb1;

        public void Init()
        {
            timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
            timer1.Interval = 10;
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            timer1.Tick += Timer1_Tick;

            ConvertedBmp = ConvertTo24(@"c:\temp\anim3.gif");
            mymem = ToStream(ConvertedBmp, ImageFormat.Bmp);

            distanceFromCenterPixels = (float)(/*183d*/ ((double)200 / 1.09289617486) * (double)distanceFromCenterKm / 200d);
            argbValuesOfTransparentTexture = new byte[bytes];

            InitializeDirectX(pb1);

            FindPoints();
            //initialize angleArray
            angleArray = new float[detectedPoints.Count];
            distanceArray = new float[detectedPoints.Count];

            for (int i = 0; i < detectedPoints.Count; i++)
            {
                CalculateAngleAndDistance(detectedPoints[i].X, detectedPoints[i].Y, out angleCalculation, out distance);

                angleArray[i] = (float)angleCalculation;
                distanceArray[i] = (float)distance;
            }
            timer1.Enabled = true;
        }

        static float angleF_ = 0.0F;
        private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (angleF_ > 360F)
            {
                angleF_ -= 360F;
            }

            ReturnTexture(scannedCloudsTexture, detectedPoints, angleArray, angleF_, bmpnew);

            DisplayOnScreen(angleF_);

            // To change direction to change += to -=
            // To change speed to raise the value 1.0d 
            angleF_ += 1.0F;
        }

        private Bitmap ConvertTo24(string inputFileName)
        {
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            Bitmap bmpIn = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(inputFileName);

            Bitmap converted = new Bitmap(bmpIn.Width, bmpIn.Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(converted))
            {
                // Prevent DPI conversion
                g.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Pixel;
                // Draw the image
                g.DrawImageUnscaled(bmpIn, 0, 0);
            }
            //converted.Save(outputFileName, ImageFormat.Bmp);
            sw.Stop();
            return converted;
        }

        public static Stream ToStream(Image image, ImageFormat formaw)
        {
            var stream = new MemoryStream();
            image.Save(stream, formaw);
            stream.Position = 0;
            return stream;
        }

        public Boolean InitializeDirectX(System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pb1)
        {

            DispMode = Manager.Adapters[Manager.Adapters.Default.Adapter].CurrentDisplayMode;
            D3Dpp = new PresentParameters();
            D3Dpp.BackBufferFormat = DispMode.Format;
            D3Dpp.PresentFlag = PresentFlag.LockableBackBuffer;

            D3Dpp.SwapEffect = SwapEffect.Discard;
            D3Dpp.PresentationInterval = PresentInterval.One; //wait for vertical sync. Synchronizes the painting with
                                                              //monitor refresh rate for smoooth animation
            D3Dpp.Windowed = true; //the application has borders

            try
            {
                D3Ddev = new Device(Manager.Adapters.Default.Adapter, DeviceType.Hardware, pb1.Handle,
                                                                           CreateFlags.SoftwareVertexProcessing, D3Dpp);
                //D3Ddev.VertexFormat = CustomVertex.PositionColored.Format;
                D3Ddev.RenderState.Lighting = false;
                D3Ddev.RenderState.CullMode = Cull.CounterClockwise;

                //load imagesBmp to panelTexture
                //panelTexture = Texture.FromBitmap(D3Ddev, imagesBmp, Usage.Dynamic, Pool.Default)

                backTexture = TextureLoader.FromStream(D3Ddev, mymem);




                //scannerTexture = TextureLoader.FromFile(D3Ddev, @"D:\Buttons\Radar\radar.png");
                scannedCloudsTexture = new Texture(D3Ddev, 512, 512, 1, Usage.Dynamic, Format.A8R8G8B8, Pool.Default);

                //sprite is used to draw the texture
                D3Dsprite = new Sprite(D3Ddev);

                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        Bitmap bmpn;
        float angle = 0;
        private void DisplayOnScreen(float angleF)
        {

            if (angle < 360)
            {
                bmpn = new Bitmap(512, 512);
                angle++;
            }
            else
            {
                angle = 361;
            }
            Surface backbuffer;
            Brush myBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(110, 0, 255, 0)); //semi transparent color to draw the rotating cone 
            Graphics g;

            //clear the backbuffer with Color.FromArgb(56, 56, 56). This is the double buffer mechanism. Drawing to offscreen 
            //backbuffer and in the end flipping it to main one which is our panelContainer 
            D3Ddev.Clear(ClearFlags.Target, Color.FromArgb(56, 56, 56), 1, 0);
            D3Ddev.BeginScene();

            //Draw Sprites 
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
            D3Dsprite.Begin(SpriteFlags.AlphaBlend);

            // bitmap with clouds 
            D3Dsprite.Draw2D(backTexture, new PointF(0, 0), 0F, new PointF(0F, 0F), Color.White);
            //the part of clouds that are inside the cone 
            D3Dsprite.Draw2D(scannedCloudsTexture, new PointF(0F, 0F), 0F, new PointF(0F, 0F), Color.White);
            //rotate cone 
            //D3Dsprite.Draw2D(scannerTexture, new PointF(104.5F, 0F), angle, new PointF(256F, 255F), Color.White); 

            D3Dsprite.Flush();
            D3Dsprite.End();
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 


            //Draw the cone. 
            using (backbuffer = D3Ddev.GetBackBuffer(0, 0, BackBufferType.Mono))
            {
                using (g = backbuffer.GetGraphics())
                {
                    g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

                    g.FillPie(myBrush, 256F - distanceFromCenterPixels, 255F - distanceFromCenterPixels,
                    distanceFromCenterPixels * 2F, distanceFromCenterPixels * 2F, angleF - 23F, 46F);
                    if (angle <= 360)
                    {

                    }

                }
            }

            D3Ddev.EndScene();
            D3Ddev.Present(); //performs the flipping 

        }

        private void CalculateAngleAndDistance(int x, int y, out double angle, out double distance)
        {
            Double dbl = -1.0d;
            Point center = new Point(256, 255);

            distance = Math.Sqrt((double)((center.Y - y) * (center.Y - y) + (center.X - x) * (center.X - x)));

            if (y == center.Y && x > center.X)
            {
                dbl = 0d;
                angle = dbl;

                return;
            }
            else if (x == center.X && y > center.Y)
            {
                dbl = 90d;
                angle = dbl;

                return;
            }
            else if (y == center.Y && x < center.X)
            {
                dbl = 180d;
                angle = dbl;

                return;
            }
            else if (x == center.X && y < center.Y)
            {
                dbl = 279d;
                angle = dbl;

                return;
            }
            else if (x == center.X && y == center.Y)
            {
                angle = dbl;

                return;
            }

            if (x > center.X && y > center.Y) //1
            {
                dbl = Math.Atan(((double)y - (double)center.Y) / ((double)x - (double)center.X));
                dbl = 180d * dbl / Math.PI;
            }
            else if (x < center.X && y > center.Y) //2
            {
                dbl = Math.Atan(((double)y - (double)center.Y) / ((double)center.X - (double)x));
                dbl = 180d * dbl / Math.PI;
                dbl = 180d - dbl;
            }
            else if (x < center.X && y < center.Y) //3
            {
                dbl = Math.Atan(((double)center.Y - (double)y) / ((double)center.X - (double)x));
                dbl = 180d * dbl / Math.PI;
                dbl += 180d;
            }
            else //4
            {
                dbl = Math.Atan(((double)center.Y - (double)y) / ((double)x - (double)center.X));
                dbl = 180d * dbl / Math.PI;
                dbl = 360d - dbl;
            }


            angle = dbl;
        }

        private void ReturnTexture(Texture texture_take, List<Point> lstPnt, float[] anglArr, float angle, Bitmap bmpNew)
        {
            int i, j, stride = 2048;
            float angleBefore, angleAfter;
            GraphicsStream textureStream;
            Boolean bl = false;

            if (bmpNew.Width != 512 && bmpNew.Height != 512)
                throw new Exception("Bitmaps must be of same size.");

            //sets texture to complete transparent 
            unsafe
            {
                fixed (byte* p = argbValuesOfTransparentTexture)
                {
                    MemSet((IntPtr)p, 0x0, argbValuesOfTransparentTexture.Length);
                }
            }


            angleAfter = angle + 23F;

            if (angleAfter >= 360F)
            {
                angleAfter -= 360F;
            }

            angleBefore = angleAfter - 46;

            if (angleBefore < 0F)
            {
                angleBefore += 360F;
                bl = true;
            }

            BitmapData bmD = bmpNew.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmpNew.Width, bmpNew.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            unsafe
            {
                byte* p = (byte*)bmD.Scan0.ToPointer();
                //checks all points and draws yellow only those who are inside the cone 
                for (i = 0; i < lstPnt.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    if (anglArr[i] == -1F)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (bl == true)
                    {
                        if (anglArr[i] <= angleAfter || anglArr[i] >= angleBefore) //if point angle is inside cone. Cone angle is 46 degrees 
                        {
                            if (distanceArray[i] <= distanceFromCenterPixels)
                            {
                                j = lstPnt[i].Y * stride + lstPnt[i].X * 4;

                                //yellow 
                                argbValuesOfTransparentTexture[j + 0] = (byte)0;
                                argbValuesOfTransparentTexture[j + 1] = (byte)255;
                                argbValuesOfTransparentTexture[j + 2] = (byte)255;
                                argbValuesOfTransparentTexture[j + 3] = (byte)255;

                                p[j] = (byte)0;
                                p[j + 1] = (byte)0;
                                p[j + 2] = (byte)255;
                                p[j + 3] = (byte)255;
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (anglArr[i] <= angleAfter && anglArr[i] >= angleBefore) //if point angle is inside cone. Cone angle is 46 degrees 
                        {
                            if (distanceArray[i] <= distanceFromCenterPixels)
                            {
                                j = lstPnt[i].Y * stride + lstPnt[i].X * 4;

                                //yellow 
                                argbValuesOfTransparentTexture[j + 0] = (byte)0;
                                argbValuesOfTransparentTexture[j + 1] = (byte)255;
                                argbValuesOfTransparentTexture[j + 2] = (byte)255;
                                argbValuesOfTransparentTexture[j + 3] = (byte)255;

                                p[j] = (byte)0;
                                p[j + 1] = (byte)0;
                                p[j + 2] = (byte)255;
                                p[j + 3] = (byte)255;
                            }

                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            //if (angle <= 360)
            //  pictureBox1.Image.Save(@"c:\coneimages\" + angle + ".gif");

            bmpNew.UnlockBits(bmD);



            {
                using (textureStream = texture_take.LockRectangle(0, LockFlags.None))
                {
                    textureStream.Write(argbValuesOfTransparentTexture);
                    texture_take.UnlockRectangle(0);
                }

                //if (angle <= 360)
                //  pictureBox1.Image.Save(@"c:\coneimages\" + angle + ".gif");
            }
        }

        private void FindPoints()
        {


            //Bitmap bmptest;
            GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();
            int x, y, p, j, wdthHght;
            int bytes;
            //byte error_ = 5;
            byte[] rgbValuesWithClouds;
            byte[] rgbValuesWithoutClouds;
            IntPtr ptr;
            Rectangle rect;
            BitmapData bitmap_Data;

            Bitmap bmpWithClouds; //No memory is allocated
            Bitmap bmpWithoutClouds; //No memory is allocated

            gp.AddEllipse(new RectangleF(73, 72, 367, 367));

            //gp.CloseFigure();

            //using the using statement, bmpWithClouds bitmap is automatically disposed at the end of statement. No memory leaks :)
            using (bmpWithClouds = new Bitmap(mymem))//@"D:\MyWeatherStation-Images-And-Icons\radartobmp.bmp")) //24 bit bitmap
            {
                rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmpWithClouds.Width, bmpWithClouds.Height);
                wdthHght = bmpWithClouds.Width;

                //Lock bitmap to copy its color information fast
                bitmap_Data = bmpWithClouds.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bmpWithClouds.PixelFormat);
                ptr = bitmap_Data.Scan0;
                bytes = bitmap_Data.Stride * bmpWithClouds.Height;

                rgbValuesWithClouds = new byte[bytes];

                //copy color information to rgbValues array
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValuesWithClouds, 0, bytes);
                //we are done copying so unlock bitmap. We dont need it anymore
                bmpWithClouds.UnlockBits(bitmap_Data);
            }


            //using the using statement, bmpWithClouds bitmap is automatically disposed at the end of statement. No memory leaks :)
            using (bmpWithoutClouds = new Bitmap(
                @"D:\C-Sharp\Download File\Downloading-File-Project-Version-012\Downloading File\bin\x86\Release\WithoutClouds.bmp"))//su + "\\WithoutClouds.bmp")) //24 bit bitmap
            {
                rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmpWithoutClouds.Width, bmpWithoutClouds.Height);

                //Lock bitmap to copy its color information fast
                bitmap_Data = bmpWithoutClouds.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bmpWithoutClouds.PixelFormat);
                ptr = bitmap_Data.Scan0;
                bytes = bitmap_Data.Stride * bmpWithoutClouds.Height;

                rgbValuesWithoutClouds = new byte[bytes];

                //copy color information to rgbValues array
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValuesWithoutClouds, 0, bytes);
                //we are done copying so unlock bitmap. We dont need it anymore
                bmpWithoutClouds.UnlockBits(bitmap_Data);
            }

            // Each position in these arrays, rgbValuesWithoutClouds and rgbValuesWithClouds, corresponds a color. eg
            // First pixel   Second pixel   Third pixel   Forth pixel .... // bitmaps
            //    B G R          B G R         B G R         B G R    .... // rgbValues arrays
            //bmptest = new Bitmap(512, 512);
            detectedPoints = new List<Point>();

            for (y = 0; y < wdthHght; y++)
            {
                j = 0;
                for (x = 0; x < wdthHght; x++)
                {

                    p = y * wdthHght * 3 + j;

                    if (rgbValuesWithClouds[p] != rgbValuesWithoutClouds[p])
                    {
                        detectedPoints.Add(new Point(x, y));
                        //bmptest.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Red);
                    }

                    j += 3;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can draw the cone to the stencil buffer and then draw the clouds only in the marked part.

Comment: Found how to do it. Should i answer my own question ? Anyway removing this line: D3Dsprite.Draw2D(backTexture, new PointF(0, 0), 0F, new PointF(0F, 0F), Color.White); did the trick. This line is drawing the bitmap with clouds. Once i removed the line the cone is keep rotating and showing the clouds only when the cone is passing over them .

Comment: Yes, post an answer that explains it.